# Failed precondition error when using Tensorflow serving to serve pretrained keras xception model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

This is the code that i am using to export the keras model into tensorflow serving format.The exported model loads up successfully in tensorflow serving( without any warnings or errors). But when i use my client to make a request to the server, i get a FailedPrecondition error.
`grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.FAILED_PRECONDITION
    details = "Attempting to use uninitialized value block11_sepconv2_bn/moving_mean`

```
import sys
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import builder as saved_model_builder
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import utils
from tensorflow.python.saved_model import tag_constants, signature_constants
from tensorflow.python.saved_model.signature_def_utils_impl import     
build_signature_def, predict_signature_def
from tensorflow.contrib.session_bundle import exporter
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' 

config = tf.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 2 , 'CPU': 12} ) 
sess = tf.Session(config=config) 
K.set_session(sess)
K._LEARNING_PHASE = tf.constant(0)
K.set_learning_phase(0) 

xception = load_model('models/xception/model.h5')
config = xception.get_config()
weights = xception.get_weights()

new_xception = Model.from_config(config)
new_xception.set_weights(weights)

export_path = 'prod_models/2'
builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
signature = predict_signature_def(inputs={'images': new_xception.input},
                              outputs={'scores': new_xception.output})
with K.get_session() as sess:
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess=sess,
                                     tags=[tag_constants.SERVING],
                                     signature_def_map={'predict': 
                                                       signature})
    builder.save()
```

- Package versions

  - Python 3.6.3
  - tensorflow-gpu 1.8.0
  - Keras 2.1.5
  - CUDA 9.0.176

Comment: I need to see how you're loading the savedmodel to understand where this error comes from

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem with the following model as I do not have access to the model file that you are using:

```
from keras.applications.xception import Xception
new_xception = Xception()
```

I can make requests to this model without issues (python 3.6.4, tf 1.8.0, keras 2.2.0). What version of TF-serving are you using?

Comment: tensorflow serving - 1.7

Comment: can you verify that the variable files are saved in a subdirectory `variables` in your export directory?

Comment: Yeah i check that, they are present around 81mb

Comment: can you maybe update the question to include your client code?

Comment: can you try and check if it still works after unfreezing some layers and do some transfer learning/fine tuning?

Comment: You can try with my code. If not, you could try aligning the version of tensorflow-serving with the version of tensorflow your are using.

Comment: Only way i can get keras models to work with tf serving is by freezing the graph and then exporting